# How to save 4d numpy array to images

Tags: python, arrays, image

I want to create an image date_set which includes 176 small images (128*128*3) from one big image (1408, 2048, 3). 
I do the following thing:
step 1. 
Load the big image and convert it to numpy array. (1408, 2048, 3) 3d array
step 2.
cut it into 176 pieces: (176, 128, 128, 3) 4d array
step 3.
I don't know how to save 176 images from 4d array in this step. Does anyone could help me to solve this problem? 
Thanks very much!

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import download_file
image_file = download_file('https://data.sdss.org/sas/dr12/boss/photoObj/frames/301/1035/3/frame-irg-001035-3-0011.jpg', cache=True )
image = imread(image_file)


def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols, c):
"""
Return an array of shape (n, nrows, ncols) where
n * nrows * ncols = arr.size

If arr is a 2D array, the returned array should look like n subblocks with
each subblock preserving the "physical" layout of arr.
"""
h, w = arr.shape[:2]
return (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols, c)
           .swapaxes(1,2)
           .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols, c))

a= image[:1408, :]
b= blockshaped(a, 128, 128, 3)
b.shape
```

b.shape = (176, 128, 128, 3)

Comment: Iterate over the first dimension and use any kind of image-export functionality of Pil(low) or scipy on the remaining 3 dimensions.

Comment: Could you help me with the code?  really appreciate.

Comment: Not without seeing any of yours. Read the docs. [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html) would be easier than PIL, but will be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible way to do it.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc

images = np.zeros((176,128,128,3)) 
for i in range(len(images)):
    scipy.misc.imsave('date_set_' + str(i) + '.jpg', images[i,:,:,:])
```

Comment: Thanks very much!